# Events in BOX api

Tags: box-api

When I try to get the events but entering a valid stream_position, I am getting the correct response. However, when I give stream_position = 0, I am getting a "out_of_date" message instead of getting the complete list of all the events in the box cache as claimed in the api documentation of box. Please find below the sequence of requests/response when stream_position is 0.

Request : Calling the get method for the url https://api.box.com/2.0/events

Response:
`{u'next_stream_position': 1388316267169, u'entries': [], u'chunk_size': 0}`

Request :Calling the options method for the url https://api.box.com/2.0/events

Response : `{u'entries': [{u'url': u'http://2.realtime.services.box.net/subscribe?channel=c403627ae43a88af895d&stream_type=all', u'max_retries': u'10', u'retry_timeout': 610, u'type': u'realtime_server', u'ttl': u'10'}], u'chunk_size': 1}`

Request:
http://2.realtime.services.box.net/subscribestream_position=0&stream_type=all&channel=%5Bu%27c403627ae43a88af895d%27%5D

Response : 
`{u'message': u'out_of_date', u'version': 1}`

Answer (score 0):

My mistake!

There is no need to use the long polling method. All we needed to do for this use case is to directly call events with parameter as zero.